# Is there a formula containing index of π (exclude index 1)

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, education

By the way, someone help me to put it into a correct category?

I know following formula containing π (3.1415926....)

- Area of Circle: π * r * r
- Area of sphere: 4 * π * r * r
- Volume of sphere: 4/3 * π * r * r * r
- I've also seen π exist in some Trigonometric formula.

But I've never seen π is used like this:

- π^2
- π^(1/2)

**Question 1:** Is there any formula that involving π's index?

**Question 2:** If my guessing "no, there isn't any" is correct, is it because this mathematical **constant** is irrational or because it is transcendental or both or other feature?

**Question 3:** How about "Natural logarithm"? Any formula involving e's index?

Comment: How about $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$?  How about $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$?

Comment: $\sqrt \pi$ appears in many [particular values of the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function)

Comment: For **1+3** combined see this [remarkable formula of Ramanujan](http://oeis.org/wiki/A_remarkable_formula_of_Ramanujan).

Comment: $\frac 12 = \frac {\sqrt{\pi}}2$ (Not really, but yes).

Comment: Take whatever you want: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Don't you mean $\left(\frac 12\right)!=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$? Otherwise it appears $\pi=1$

Comment: @Riley my bad! Funny I can not edit my comment now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Volume of a $5$-dimensional ball: $\frac8{15}\pi^2 r^5$.
- Volume of a $6$-dimensional ball: $\frac16\pi^3 r^6$.
- [Generalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball).
- $1+\frac1{16}+\frac1{81}+\frac1{256}+\cdots+\frac1{n^4}+\cdots=\frac1{90}\pi^4$.
- $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx=\pi^{1/2}$.
- Many more!!

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes, good, but I already had an example with $\pi^2$ :)

Answer (score 2):

Very important in probability:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\; dx = \sqrt{\pi}$$